LazyGrid with onTap gesture on items does not work as intended with sheet presentation
I am trying to understand @State. Ignoring the view model in the picture, I am trying to present a view modally with sheet modifier on tapping any item on my lazygrid. For some reason an empty view is presented as the selected item is always nil for some reason.
This is how my state properties looks
@State private var selectedFollower : Follower? = nil
@State var showFollowerDetail = false

This is the presentation on list
ForEach(followers, id: \.self) { follower in
      GridCells(follower: follower)
           .onTapGesture {
                  selectedFollower = follower
                  showFollowerDetail = true
           }
}

And this is the sheet modifier
.sheet(isPresented: $showFollowerDetail, content: {
      if let selectedFollower{
            UserInfoView(follower: selectedFollower)
      }
})


Note, you should not have a dot . before a .@State private.... To fix your problem, try using .sheet(item:...), there many posts and answers about this. See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

Good catch on the typo regarding the dot before @State. I fixed the question. But I want to understand why the above way is not working. Since the source of truth for the view is changing and I do have a state that holds the selected follower, why would the value be nil when I tap on the grid item

AFAIK, the .sheet(isPresented: ... closure does not capture the variable, that is why there is a .sheet(item: ...). You could capture it yourself, using .sheet(isPresented: $showFollowerDetail) { [selectedFollower] in ...

(Although it seems like an internal bug to me), it happens when you try to define a separate flag State and manually manage it and sometimes it gets out of sync somehow (like when there is a race between the render engine and the closure capture).
To work around it, you can drive the Binding<Bool> directly from the source of truth to make sure it is always in sync:
@State private var selectedFollower: Follower?
var showFollowerDetail: Binding<Bool> {
    .init {
        selectedFollower != nil
    } set: {
        guard !$0 else { return }
        selectedFollower = nil
    }
}

Or simply use the other initializer that accepts an optional as recommended:
.sheet(item: $selectedFollower) { selectedFollower in
     UserInfoView(follower: selectedFollower)
}


The other initializer works fine. I do have a view model where I have isSet on the @Published selectedFollower to toggle the showFollowerDetail. That is probably the way to go using MVVC but wanted to see why the above failed. Any idea where I can learn more on topic like  "race between the render engine and the closure capture"?

To get a better answer, please provide a more detailed sample, this will help ensure that it aligns closely with your original intentions. About the topic, a comprehensive overview of WWDC videos from iOS 13 where Apple introduced the SwiftUI, especially those with titles like “Demystify ” can provide valuable insights. Additionally, detailed Stack Overflow answers where people uncover the internal mysteries of SwiftUI can be extremely helpful.

I did an analysis a long time ago of this behavior
SwiftUI: Understanding .sheet / .fullScreenCover lifecycle when using constant vs @Binding initializers
But in short it appears that SwiftUI is "smart enough" to not re-render the parent View when showFollowerDetail is called because the change of the Bool doesn't actually affect the parent.
Therefore, when the sheet is presented the current value is the same as it was at the last render of the parent body when the sheet was created.
There are a few ways around this that work in different scenarios.
1.
sheet(item: $selectedFollower) 

is the "right way" for this scenario.
2. $selectedFollower.projectedValue also has the new value.
3. You can also alter UserInfoView to use Binding instead of a let for follower.
4. Use selectedFollower and/or showFollowerDetail somewhere else in the parent's body so the DynamicProperty decides to give the State the new value.
The idea general idea is to either use the projectValue or give SwiftUI a reason to update the wrappedValue.
